# hyphsubst conflicts with inputenc

Tags: hyphenation, input-encodings

If I load inputenc in combination with hyphsubst the hyphenation works partially. It works for many words, but it does not work for 'Starrkörpertransformationsparameter' if inputenc is loaded

hyphenation working:

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}

% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
\end{document}
```

hyphenation does not work:

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem is that you don't have also `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem due to `inputenc`. You also need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or TeX won't hyphenate words past an accent.

In your example without `inputenc`, hyphenation points are found, but just because the accented characters are ignored.

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
  Starrkörpertransformationsparameter
\end{document}
```

[image]

Slightly different results are obtained if `\usepackage{microtype}` is loaded, but this is expected; here's the result, the text is the same as before, the preamble is

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
```

[image]